# Speed up access to many std::maps with same key

Tags: c++, performance, boost

Suppose you have a `std::vector<std::map<std::string, T> >`. You know that all the `map`s have the same keys. They might have been initialized with

```
typedef std::map<std::string, int> MapType;
std::vector<MapType> v;
const int n = 1000000;
v.reserve(n);
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    std::map<std::string, int> m;
    m["abc"] = rand();
    m["efg"] = rand();
    m["hij"] = rand();
    v.push_back(m);
}
```

Given a key (e.g. `"efg"`), I would like to extract all values of the maps for the given key (which definitely exists in every map).

Is it possible to speed up the following code?

```
std::vector<int> efgValues;
efgValues.reserve(v.size());
BOOST_FOREACH(MapType const& m, v)
{
    efgValues.push_back(m.find("efg")->second);
}
```

Note that the values are not necessarily `int`. As profiling confirms that most time is spent in the find function, I was thinking about whether there is a (GCC and MSVC compliant C++03) way to avoid locating the element in the map based on the key for every single map again, because the structure of all the maps is equal.

If no, would it be possible with `boost::unordered_map` (which is 15% slower on my machine with the code above)? Would it be possible to cache the hash value of the string?

**P.S.: I know that having a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<T> >` would solve my problem. However, I cannot change the data structure (which is actually more complex than what I showed here).**

Comment: Map is a tree so your idea wont work, but unordered_map maybe..

Comment: I know, but the tree traversal (involving key comparisons) is still always the same.

Comment: Unless all the trees filled in an identical fashion, it is likely that their structure isnt similar.

Comment: And I am not too clear on what happens when hash tables need to resize, if old hashs are still valid, if not, this wouldnt work reliably with them either.

Comment: Currently, the keys are added in the same order for every map (although I am not sure if I would like to depend on this...)

Comment: @Philipp: You cannot change the original data structure, but what stops you from keeping an additional data structure which faciliates faster lookup? You could have `std::map<std::string, std::vector<T> >` as additional data structure? So when you update the first one, update the second one also. Is it posssible? If it is, then let me know I will post it as answer :P

Comment: @Philipp: Are the keys constantly changing or do they stay the same? If they stay the same then you might as well just use a sorted vector instead of a map...

Comment: Depending on your use case, migrating to a [Multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/) might make a lot of sense even beyond this one case.

Comment: @Nawaz: Unfortunately, this isn't possible (or, to be more precise, I'd really want to avoid it because it doesn't fit in the current data structure. ) - sorry :-)

Comment: @Mehrdad: What do you mean with changing/stay the same? I do not know which keys are in the maps. If you put my second code block into a function, they would differ from call to call.

Comment: @KarthikT: Actually, I rather have `struct MyData { int a; int b; map<string, T> m; }; vector<MyData> v; `

Comment: @Philipp You should add that to the question to shut up ppl like me :P. You can still preprocess it into a MultiMap if your access code runs multiple times.

Comment: Btw do all your keys exist on all your maps? Maybe just make them into members of MyData?

Answer (score 2):

You can cache and playback the sequence of comparison results using a stateful comparator. But that's just nasty; the solution is to adjust the data structure. There's no "cannot." Actually, adding a stateful comparator is changing the data structure. That requirement rules out almost anything.

Another possibility is to create a linked list across the objects of type `T` so you can get from each map to the next without another lookup. If you might be starting at any of the maps (please, just refactor the structure) then a circular or doubly-linked list will do the trick.

> As profiling confirms that most time is spent in the find function

Keeping the tree data structures and optimizing the comparison can only speed up the comparison. Unless the time is spent in `operator< (std::string const&, std::string const&)`, you need to change the way it's linked together.

Comment: Of course you are right that there's no "cannot". As said in a comment above, it's more a "would like to avoid" (seeing the whole picture). Besides that, I was just curious to learn something I might not know - so +1 for your ideas!